# Excel, drop-down list changes contents of another cell, not formulaic

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

How do I make one cell display a value based on another cell choice that is a drop-down list selection? I don't know how to do macros, and I have tried researching. I think the question about displaying a custom state based on an sls file is close, but I don't know what and sls file is or how to code. Is there a simple way to tie two cell values together? eg. I want to be able to change the dollar value displayed in cell B (which represents a real cost of a subscription) based on what subscription choice I select from a drop-down list in cell A.

Comment: I only mean that it is not a formula I am trying to get to work, i am just trying to coordinate the contents of two cells. I tried the VLOOKUP, and I don't think I am savvy enough to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Say cell **A1** has a *Data Validation* pull-down allowing you to select one of:

```
cat
dog
bird
snake
```

In another cell enter:

<strike>=LOOKUP(A1,{"cat","dog","bird","snake"},{10,20,30,40})</strike>

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{"bird","cat","dog","snake"},{10,20,30,40})
```

**The list in the formula must be in alphabetic order.**

Comment: So, that kind of worked. I am sure I am doing something wrong, but, in terms of your formula, a am getting the following result:

Comment: if A is Cat, B is 10. if A is dog, B is 30. If A is bird, B is N/A. if A is snake, B is 40.  I  have scrutinized the third A value and B value, and it doesn't matter. Whatever I choose as the third value in either cell comes back as N/A in B.

Comment: Notice I am using **C1** to hold the formula.